# Insert Image in a pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

How do I solve this one.

`fpdf.php` is on `fpdf.org` and  my image path is correct:

```
<?php

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($dir_assets_img.'code.png');
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

> Warning: fopen(view/assets/img/code.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/inceptum/public_html/model/pdf/fpdf.php on line 1232
>   FPDF error: Can't open image file: view/assets/img/code.png

```
<?php

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($dir_assets_img.'inceptum.jpg');
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

> Warning: getimagesize(view/assets/img/inceptum.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/inceptum/public_html/model/pdf/fpdf.php on line 1213
>   FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: view/assets/img/inceptum.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP clearly tells you it can't find the file.
Try to use an absolute path from root(/) like this:

```
/home/inceptum/view/assets/img/inceptum.jpg
```

And then make sure the image is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your`$dir_assets_img`, if you sure the dir is correct, then you should check your image file name. I found the same case, when using image file name which include space, this error will be show when call the image in fpdf.

Hope that can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a problem that arises due to URL linking .You can try first defining the URL and storing it in a variable before pushing it into the Image().

```
`$image=ImageName;`
```

`$ImageURL ="imageDirectory/".$image ;`
then finally

`$pdf = new FPDF(); $pdf->AddPage(); $pdf->Image($imageURL'); $pdf->Output();`